# What is your recommended workaround to deal with inconsistent API behavior design of google-gson

Tags: gson

Just that recently, I came across some inconsistent API behavior of google-gson.

### Non-empty string but with invalid syntax

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
//  com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException thrown
gson.fromJson("{{", Map.class);
```

### Empty string

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
//  Returns null
gson.fromJson("", Map.class);
```

### No-empty string with all space

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
//  Returns null
gson.fromJson("  ", Map.class);
```

### null string

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
//  Returns null
gson.fromJson((String)null, Map.class)
```

This problem is being reported in https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=457 The status is won't fixed due to backwards-compatible.

I was wondering, what is your usual workaround on the problem?

### Workaround 1 : Check for string before passing in gson

```
if (string != null && !string.trim().isEmpty())
```

### Workaround 2 : Check for returned value of gson

```
Map m = gson.fromJson(string, Map.class);
if (m != null) {
}
```

### Workaround 3 : Use TypeAdapter and catch using generic Exception

```
try {
    gson.getAdapter(Map.class).fromJson(string);
} catch (Exception ex) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think stackoverflow is the correct forum for this, since it seems an opinion based question to me, which would make if off-topic.

That said, i think workaround 2 is the best. There might be other strings, which you do not know, that make fromJson return null instead of throwing an exception; workaround 2 handles that while workaround 1 doesn't. I don't like workaround 3 either, because there might be other exceptions in the `try`ed code, which might get caught by your exception handler though the handler isn't really prepared to handle them.